# How to improve accuracy of estimateAffine2D (or estimageRigidTransform) in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have two sets of points, one from time t-1 and current time t. The first set was generated using `goodFeaturesToTrack`, and the latter from using `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK()`. Using these two sets of points, I then estimate a transformation matrix via `estimateAffine2DPartial()` in order to keep track of its scale & rotation. Code snippet is listed below:

```
// Precompute image pyramids
maxLvl = cv::buildOpticalFlowPyramid(_imgPrev, imPyr1, _winSize, maxLvl, true);
maxLvl = cv::buildOpticalFlowPyramid(tmpImg, imPyr2, _winSize, maxLvl, true);

// Optical flow call for tracking pixels
cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(imPyr1, imPyr2, _currentPoints, nextPts, status, err, _winSize, maxLvl, _terminationCriteria, 0, 0.000001);

// Get transformation matrix between the two data sets
cv::Mat H = cv::estimateAffinePartial2D(_currentPoints, nextPts, inlier_mask, cv::RANSAC, 10.0, 2000, 0.99);
```

Using H, I then map my masking points using `perspectiveTransform()`. The result seems accurate for the first few dozen frames until I notice some *drift* (in terms of rotation) occurring when the object I am tracking continues to rotate (usually when rotation becomes > M_PI). I'm honestly stumped on where the culprit is, but my main suspicion is perhaps my window size for optical flow might be too small, or too big. However, tweaking the window size did not seem to help, the position of my object is still accurate, but the estimated rotation (and scale) got worse. Can anyone hope to shed a light on this?

Warm regards and thanks.

EDIT: Images attached to show drift issue

[image: Starting Frame]

Starting Frame

[image: First few frames -- Rotation OK]

First few frames -- Rotation OK

[image: Z-Rotation Drift occurs -- See Anchor Line]

Z-Rotation Drift occurs -- see anchor line has drifted towards the red rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucas Kanade tracker needs more features. Guess the tracking template you provided is not good enough.

(1) Try with other feature rich real images? e.g [Opencv feautre tracking template image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAfMV.png)
(2) fix scale. Since you are doing simulation, you can try to anchor the size first.

calcOpticalFlowPyrLK is widely used in visual inertial state estimation studies. such as Semi direct visual odometry or VINSMONO. You can try to find the code inside those project to see how other people is playing with the feature and parameters

Comment: I suppose you are correct, though I was hoping that this template would have provided enough corners for OpenCV to correctly estimate its Affine transformations over time. I will need to do more tests.